# select html to json conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, alpacajs

I have an alpaca form with select ui element where I can select multiple values and save the form.When i save the form the JSON using `JSON.stringify(val)` the generated of the form is having problem. JSON is having only ids of selected elements.I want the JSON containing both the ids and values

```
<select id="alpaca4" multiple="multiple" size="5" name="roles" class="alpaca-control form-control">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option> 
</select>
```

The generated json format is :

```
{"roles":["1","2"]}
```

The format iam expecting is :

```
{"roles":["1":"One","2":"Two"]}
```

Comment: `["1":"One","2":"Two"]` is not a valid `Array-of-Objects`

Comment: `["1":"One","2":"Two"]` is not valid JSON of any sort.

Comment: "When i save the form the json using JSON.stringify(val) " — How are you defining `val`?

Comment: val = this.getValue() which gives the object notation of the form

Comment: please find the correct json format {"roles":[{"1":"One"},{"2":"Two"}]}

Comment: getValue is the method provided by alpaca js library

Answer (score 3):

> Use `jQuery#map`

```js
var mapped = $('#alpaca4 option').map(function() {
  var obj = {};
  obj[this.value] = this.textContent;
  return obj;
});
console.log(mapped.get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="alpaca4" multiple="multiple" size="5" name="roles" class="alpaca-control form-control">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.My form has many other ui elements along with the select ui element.I need to generate json of the entire form which can be achieved by JSON.stringify(val) and the json of select element alone should be as you suggested .How to do this

Comment: @ramnar, Are you using `serialize` ?

Comment: im using var val = this.getValue(); var json = JSON.stringify(val)

Comment: @ramnar, Never heard of `getValue` method ;(

Answer (score 0):

You should only persist the values, not the labels.  Alpaca is doing the right thing here according to how html forms work.